# ASP.NET MVC Url.Action and route name value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am using asp.net mvc 2 and create localization based on routes.

1. my route looks like: `{culture}/{controller}/{action}`
2. I go to my home controller: `en/Home/Index`
3. my home controller view have a links to other controllers:

   ```
   <a href='<%= Url.Action("Prods","Products") %>' >Products</a>
   <a href='<%= Url.Action("Index","About") %>' >About</a>
   ```

First link generated code: `/en/Products/Prods` but second one generate: `/Home/Index`

I can't understand why `Url.Action` skips the `{culture}` route parameter when I pass value `Index` in argument action? What am I doing wrong?

Route configuration:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute("Login", // Route name
                "{controller}/Index", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Login", action = "Index" } // Parameter defaults
                ).RouteHandler = new SingleCultureMvcRouteHandler();

routes.MapRoute("Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
               );
```

Then

```
foreach (Route r in routes)
{
    if (!(r.RouteHandler is SingleCultureMvcRouteHandler))
    {
       r.RouteHandler = new MultiCultureMvcRouteHandler();

       r.Url = "{culture}/" + r.Url;

       if (r.Defaults == null)
       {
          r.Defaults = new RouteValueDictionary();
       }

       r.Defaults.Add("culture", "en");

       if (r.Constraints == null)
       {
          r.Constraints = new RouteValueDictionary();
       }

       r.Constraints.Add("culture", new CultureConstraint(cultures));
    }
 }
```

Thanks for all help

Comment: If you include your full route configuration it's easier to find the problem.

Comment: @João Angelo Thanks for response please look for update

Comment: @marc_s Thanks, i add it after all routes here: r.Url = "{culture}/" + r.Url;

Comment: Check out [Phil Haack's Route debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) which is a great tool to understand which routes get picked and why ...

Comment: @marc_s Thanks a lot for useful route debugger link

Comment: @SanjaMelnichuk can you tell me where you added foreach (Route r in routes)
I have same concern to use web URL/{culturename}.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

When generating URL your best options is to always use the route names because this way you do not get into the subtleties of the algorithm used to select the route that will be used to generate the URL.

My advice if for you not to use `Url.Action` and instead use [`Url.RouteUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.routeurl.aspx) which allows you to specify the name of the route that should be used to construct the URL.

By always using route names you also make your code more robust to changes, for example, you can add new routes without having to worry that they might break your existing code for URL generation.

Answer (score 1):

For purposes of building a Url.Action link, any `Index` action without an `id` token will match the `Login` route.  The Login route uses the SingleCultureMvcRouteHandler, so the culture will not be prepended to those links.