# Use a specific route with Url.Action

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I have two routes declared in my route config like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "SpecificAction",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}-{id2}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Main", action = "SpecificAction", id = UrlParameter.Optional, id2 = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "DefaultNoParams",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/",
    defaults: new { controller = "Main", Action = "Index" },
    namespaces: new string[1] { "Project.Controllers" }
);
```

I have two controller actions that look like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult TheAction()
{

}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TheAction([ModelBinder(typeof(SpecificModelBinder))] SpecificModel model)
{

}
```

I want a link to the first of these actions in my view, so I generate one using `Url.Action`:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("TheAction", "Main")">The Action</a>
```

However, this outputs the url `http://site/Main/TheAction/-` (note the dash at the end, which seems to indicate that my `SpecificAction` route is being used.

Is there some way I can call `Url.Action` with a specific route? Or is there any other way I can avoid this dash appearing in the url?

Comment: The routing table doesn't affect how `Url.Action` renders a URL... So your link is rendered as `<a href="http://site/Main/TheAction/-">`?

Comment: @ChrisHardie Yes, I just want to avoid that.

Comment: Odd... What is rendered when you add this to your View: `<a href="@Url.Action("TheAction")">The Action</a>`

Comment: @ChrisHardie Same thing...

Comment: Where is `http://site` coming from?

Comment: @ChrisHardie Sorry, it doesn't literally say `site`. It's just the dash I'm looking at avoiding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change the order of your routes. Put the `SpecificAction` route after the `DefaultNoParams` route like below:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "DefaultNoParams",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/",
    defaults: new { controller = "Main", Action = "Index" },
    namespaces: new string[1] { "Project.Controllers" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "SpecificAction",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}-{id2}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Main", action = "SpecificAction", id = UrlParameter.Optional, id2 = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Update: To answer below requested question:

> Can you provide some detail as to how the route table mappings would
>   affect how Url.Action generates a URL such that a dash was being
>   appended?

First, OP used below code in the view:

```
 <a href="@Url.Action("TheAction", "Main")">The Action</a>
```

it generates:

```
 <a href="/Main/TheAction">The Action</a>
```

The reason why there is a dash is because both id parameters are optional, so without both ids, there will only be a dash and it satisfies below route conditions.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "SpecificAction",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}-{id2}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Main", action = "SpecificAction", 
            id = UrlParameter.Optional, id2 = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

If one of the ids are not optional, it'll keep checking the next routes. But OP needed the id parameters to be optional, that's why my solution is to change the route orders.

Comment: @Lin Can you provide some detail as to how the route table mappings would affect how `Url.Action` generates a URL such that a dash was being appended?

Comment: @ChrisHardie, I updated the answer to have more details, take a look.

Comment: Well, the question was how to use a *specific* route, not how to setup routes. This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 12):

Duplicate question is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938332/asp-net-mvc-url-action-and-route-name-value)

In short, use `Url.RouteUrl()` intead of `Url.Action()` to get the correct URL.

In your case, you can even use `@Html.RouteLink()` to get the whole anchor tag if you wish.